# SQLite on CSV file

Tags: sqlite

I have a small statistics program, which you can point to a CSV file. It tries to determine certain properties (like i.E. which columns might be a date). Lately I have been reading a lot about SQLite and would like to port my application to make us of it, as this would make it easier to create new statitics as only a new select would have to be written.

Now what I would like to know is, I know that SQLite can operate in memory, but of course I don't want to always load the whole file into memory as this can become rather big. So I would like to point SQLite to the CSV file and provide the column information, so that I can do queries on it. It would also be cool if I could create an index in memory (or a temprorary directory) so that the statistics will run faster. This would not need to modify the CSV, only do selects.

Can this be done out of the box? If not, can I write my own filemanager and connect it to SQLite, to achieve this? Writing my own filemanager would only be an option if the effort is not to big, as I don't want to write a full blown database code.

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: The biggest one is 8MB so far, but this tool is generic, so it might have to handle bigger files as well. However, I don't expect REALLY big files in the range of 50 or 100MB. Do you think it might be better to create that in memory?

Comment: That's not that big. A modern computer has 4GB+ of memory. With SQLite you can always create a database in a file which can be very large.

Comment: Please provide a short sample of your data and the of the queries you want to run on it. Then we can advise you about indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite supports reading from a file:

```
$ cat data.csv
Cheese,7,12.3
Bacon,8,19.4
Eggs,3,20.3

# With no filename SQLite creates the database in memory.
$ sqlite3
sqlite> create table data (name text, units integer, price double);
sqlite> .separator ','
sqlite> .import data.csv data
sqlite> select * from data;
Cheese,7,12.3
Bacon,8,19.4
Eggs,3,20.3
```

You can add constrains and [indexes](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) on this table to help you with your analysis.

Comment: And what does this do? Does it create a separate databasefile (which I would like to avoid) or does it create it fully in memory (which might be acceptable depending on the size)? Or does it only reference the file as I originally wanted? I would like to keep this app selfcontained, without spreading files on the client computer.

Comment: With no filename, `sqlite3` creates the database in memory. See the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html).

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed the comment. :) Thanks!